# How to set delimeter when opening csv file creating with java

Tags: java, csv

I created some csv file with java:

```
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("test.csv");
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);
        out.println(sb.toString());
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
```

now when I want to open this file with libre office there is still question which delimeter should use. How I can set some default delimeter and skip this question ?

Comment: As the name suggest CSV(Comma Separated Values). Use "," as default delimeter

Comment: The question is not related with Java and CSV but only with LibreOffice.

Comment: I dont want use, but |

Comment: why it is related only with libre office ? When I open different csv file I didnt any start question

Answer (score 0):

The delimiter you use is whatever you used to construct the contents of `sb`.

Also, you want to call `flush()` and `close()` on `out`, not `writer`.  Your code may leave some data buffered in the `PrintWriter` and not properly output to the file.